# Regex: negative lookarounds with zero or more characters between

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a negative lookbehind AND a negative lookahead and so far it's ALMOST working. I have googled, I have searched stackOverflow, but can not find my exact issue. What I am trying to achieve is to capture any text within brackets AS LONG AS they are not found between my `<code></code>` tags.

**My regex attempt**

`(?<!<code>)\[(.*?)\](?!<\/code>)`

**Test Text**

```
[bracket]                                           <-- currently matches (ok)
<code>[bracket]                                     <-- currently does NOT match (ok)
[bracket]</code>                                    <-- currently does NOT match (ok)
<code> some text [bracket] other text </code>       <-- currently matches (!!NOT OK!!)
<code>[bracket]</code>                              <-- currently does NOT match (ok)
```

I'm really having problems getting around the fact that you must have a fixed width in a negative lookbehind/negative lookahead. I've tried anything from trying to grab any character between the `<code>` and the bracket, but that just grabs the `<code>` tag and matches with almost all the examples above. I've tried the `^` character to try to exclude any lines with `<code>` but that ended up just excluding everything. I'm at my wits end. Any direction is truly appreciated!!

Comment: What about `<code>foobar[bracket]`, with no `</code>`? Or will that not occur?

Comment: This may be difficult to handle using regex, ideally you should use an XML/HTML parser.  There are many edge cases here which would be hard to handle with regex alone.

Comment: No, I only need to exclude the brackets that happen INSIDE ```<code></code>``` tags. It needs to have both the opening and closing tag.

Comment: In your examples `<code>[bracket]` doesn't have closing tag and `[bracket]</code>` doesn't have closing tag, so these `[brackets]` **are not** inside `<code>...</code>`. Why shouldn't they match?

Comment: It should extend multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
<code>[\s\S]*?</code>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\[.+?\]
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/x0CDKL/1)

Comment: I am not familiar with some of this syntax so I will do more research on these, but for the time being it looks like it works!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Anna: You're welcome, glad it helps. You'll find usefull info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24534782/372239)